# References not recognized, issue only with a particular .Net project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, reference

I have an issue at work, with a .Net Project. So I cloned the project from git, and I tried to build the project, but many references like `System.dll` or `System.Data.dll` are not recognized. Even though I've tried to add them manually, they are still not recognized.

This issue is just for this project, I had other projects that I worked on that could recognize all these references from `.Net Framework`. Could somebody tell me what is the problem, please? I am dealing with this issue for a while.

Comment: Inspect the csproj files for the difference?

Comment: it doesn't work:( but I don't understand, why I have this issue, only with this certain project? It has never happend before.